# Question : l'inversion "-il" est-elle nécessaire ?

Tags: questions, pronom-de-reprise, inversion

Est-ce qu'on dit :

- Quel jour vous conviendrait ?

ou

- Quel jour vous conviendrait-il ?

Answer (score 1):

Non, l'inversion n'est pas nécessaire.

En revanche, on ajoute typiquement *le mieux*, ce qui donne  *Quel jour vous conviendrait le mieux ?*

Comment: merci! Mais, les 2 possibilités sont justes!?

Comment: @Walki Oui. La forme sans « -il » est plus courante mais les deux sont correctes.